# ASP.net get max value from Profile field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, profile, membership

I have a classic ASP website containing a users table with a `ID_USER` field (int, primary key, auto increment). The `ID_USER` value is used to track user's activity and is saved in other tables as part of the "Saved by","Saved date" logic.
Now, the website was updated and moved to ASP.NET, with the authentication rewritten using the ASP.NET membership and Profile providers. The old user's table was imported in the new structure. The `ID_USER` field became a Profile value in the new Membership/Profile logic.
All the other tables remained the same becouse of the compatibility between the two websites.

Question:
When creating new users I need to set the value for the `ID_USER` field too.
How can I do this? Can I somehow get the max value of the `ID_USER` profile field?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating an additional table with an auto increment field. I set the first record starting where my old table user ID ends. 
Now I can read and write the the ID from the temporary table and use it for the Profile value every time I create a new user.